# How to have a CASE WHEN query with multiple THEN in it?

Tags: sql, pyspark

My code has been written as:

```
SELECT name, age,
  CASE WHEN abs(10 - mean(valueLeft)) < abs(10 - mean(valueRight)) THEN stddev(valueLeftMagnitude) ELSE stddev(valueRightMagnitude) END as value1,
  CASE WHEN abs(10 - mean(valueLeft)) < abs(10 - mean(valueRight)) THEN mean(valueLeftMagnitude) ELSE mean(valueRightMagnitude) END as value2,
  CASE WHEN abs(10 - mean(valueLeft)) < abs(10 - mean(valueRight)) THEN median(valueLeftMagnitude) ELSE median(valueRightMagnitude) END as value3
FROM table
GROUP BY name, age
```

As the WHEN statement in all three CASE are same I want not to repeat them. Is there any way to do it?

EXAMPLE : I want something like -

```
SELECT name, age,
  CASE WHEN abs(10 - mean(valueLeft)) < abs(10 - mean(valueRight))
    THEN stddev(valueLeftMagnitude) ELSE stddev(valueRightMagnitude) END as value1,
    THEN mean(valueLeftMagnitude) ELSE mean(valueRightMagnitude) END as value2,
    THEN median(valueLeftMagnitude) ELSE median(valueRightMagnitude) END as value3
FROM table
GROUP BY name, age
```

Please help out.

Comment: No. Cut&Paste&Modify.

Comment: Tag your DBMS. sql-server has cross apply which can be handy here.

Comment: An embedded select could be useful too, i.e the embedded query does the calculation, the outer query does the selection.

Answer (score 1):

This is how an **embedded select** can make sure you do the `case` calculation only once:

```
SELECT perprocessed.name, perprocessed.age, stddev(perprocessed.valueMagnitude), mean(perprocessed.valueMagnitude), median(perprocessed.valueLeftMagnitude) from
(SELECT
  name,
  age,
  CASE WHEN abs(10 - mean(valueLeft)) < abs(10 - mean(valueRight)) THEN valueLeftMagnitude ELSE valueRightMagnitude END as valueMagnitude
  FROM table) as perprocessed
GROUP BY perprocessed.name, perprocessed.age
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is very readable and I see no real disadvantage in copy-pasting the expression. If you want to have this evaluation only once, the query gets slightly more complicated, as you'd go in two steps:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN which = 'left' THEN stddev_left ELSE stddev_right END AS value1,
  CASE WHEN which = 'left' THEN mean_left   ELSE mean_right   END AS value2,
  CASE WHEN which = 'left' THEN median_left ELSE median_right END AS value3
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    name, 
    age, 
    CASE WHEN abs(10 - mean(valueLeft)) < abs(10 - mean(valueRight)) 
         THEN 'left' ELSE 'right' END AS which,
    stddev(valueLeftMagnitude) AS stddev_left,
    stddev(valueRightMagnitude) AS stddev_right,
    mean(valueLeftMagnitude) AS mean_left,
    mean(valueRightMagnitude) AS mean_right,
    median(valueLeftMagnitude) AS median_left,
    median(valueRightMagnitude) median_right
  FROM table 
  GROUP BY name, age
) grouped;
```